# Getting data to display in shiny using rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am making a shiny app that uses rMarkdown, which is a little different than making a straight shiny app in that you don't use a ui and server section.

I want to display a table in Shiny using rMarkdown.

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---



### Data

```{r echo=FALSE}
n <- c(2, 3, 5)
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
myDataFrame <- data.frame(n,s,b)

tableOutput("view")
textOutput("message")

output$view <-renderTable({myDataFrame})

output$message <- renderText({"test test test"})
````

The table "view" and the message "message" are not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the assignment:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
n <- c(2, 3, 5)
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
myDataFrame <- data.frame(n,s,b)

tableOutput("view")
textOutput("message")

renderTable({myDataFrame})

renderText({"test test test"})
```
````

[image]